# Setting Labels on Vector features in OpenLayers 5

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson

I am following [this very big example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-labels.html) to set labels on the style of the vector but it's confusing.

The labels should be the Plot numbers, of each feature, which come from the JSON file.

Also i have seen [this API](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Graticule.html#~GraticuleLabelDataType). How can I get the data and display it?

```
new ol.style.Text({
  font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
  textBaseline: 'bottom',
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)'
  }),
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
    width: 3
  })
});
```

---

```
var style_simple = new ol.style.Style({
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: 'khaki'
  }),
   stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'blue',
      width: 2,
      opacity:1
    })
});

var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'JS/getjson.json',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    }),style:style_simple
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [roadlayer,vector],
    controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([new ol.control.ScaleLine()]),
    view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([33.33386, 35.14710]),
    zoom: 14,
    maxZoom: 19
  })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Dataform's answer is correct but creating a new style object every time the function is called is inefficient and can, with large numbers of features, cause performance issues.  It is better to predefine a style and set the text property as required

```
let style = new ol.style.Style({
    // ...........
    text: new ol.style.Text({
      text: ''
    })
    // ...........
  });

let styleFunction = function (feature, resolution) {
  style.getText().setText(feature.get("fieldname_for_plotnumber"));
  return style;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a function to the `style` option of the vector layer. The function is called for each feature and must return a style object.

```
let styleFunction = function (feature, resolution) {
  return new ol.style.Style({
    // ...........
    text: new ol.style.Text({
      text: feature.get("fieldname_for_plotnumber")
    })
    // ...........
  });
}

let vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  // ...........
  style: styleFunction
})
```

Comment: getting error on  `text: feature.get("parcel_nbr")`: TypeError: t.split is not a function

Comment: I have avoided that error by declaring a variable in the function : `var getParcelTXT = feature.get("parcel_nbr")+"";`